# collision detection on rectangle and ball

Tags: actionscript-3

i am build ballz game in action script3.
i am facing a problem in corner of rectangle when hit ball it cannot determine ball next position left,or bottom.

this is my code plz help me.
this is the collision function that check direction of ball

`if (isColliding)
            {
                var brick:Rectangle = hitBrick.getBounds(this);

```
            var bl:int = ba.x - (ball.width / 2);
            var br:int = ba.x + (ball.width / 2);
            var bt:int = ba.y - (ball.height / 2);
            var bb:int = ba.y + (ball.height / 2);

            var hl:int = pt.x - (hitBrick.width / 2);
            var hr:int = pt.x + (hitBrick.width / 2);
            var ht:int = pt.y - (hitBrick.height / 2);
            var hb:int = pt.y + (hitBrick.height / 2);

            if (hb <= bt)
            {

                ConsoleUtil.consoleIt("TableScreen.as :: chkColision - " + "Bottom.");
                _totalScore++;
                ball._orignalYSpeed = -ball.yspeed;
                ball.yspeed = -ball.yspeed + 5;
                ball._stopBall = true;
                ball._bottomOne = true;
                ball.updateCounterInBricks(hitBrick);

                return;
            }

            if ((hl >= bl))
            {
                ConsoleUtil.consoleIt("TableScreen.as :: chkColision - Left");
                _hitOnWall = true;
                ball._orignalXSpeed = -ball.xspeed;
                var xSp:Number = ball.xspeed = -ball.xspeed - 5;
                ball._left = true;
                ball.updateCounterInBricks(hitBrick);
                _totalScore++;
                return;
            }

            if(hb<=bb)
            {
                ConsoleUtil.consoleIt("TableScreen.as :: chkColision - " + "Bottom.");
                _totalScore++;
                ball._orignalYSpeed = -ball.yspeed;
                ball.yspeed = -ball.yspeed + 5;
                ball._stopBall = true;
                ball._bottomOne = true;
                ball.updateCounterInBricks(hitBrick);
                return;
            }
            if ((hr <= br))
            {
                ConsoleUtil.consoleIt("TableScreen.as :: chkColision - Rigth");
                _hitOnWall = true;
                ball._orignalXSpeed = -ball.xspeed;
                var xSp:Number = ball.xspeed = -ball.xspeed + 5;
                ball._left = true;
                ball._stopBall = true;
                ball.updateCounterInBricks(hitBrick);
                _totalScore++;
                return;
            }
            if (ht >= bt)
            {
                ConsoleUtil.consoleIt("TableScreen.as :: chkColision - " + "Top");
                _totalScore++;
                ball._orignalYSpeed = -ball.yspeed;
                ball.yspeed = -ball.yspeed - 5;

                ball._topOne = true;
                ball._stopBall = true;
                ball.updateCounterInBricks(hitBrick);
                return;
            }

        }`
```

Comment: You need to process corner hit as special collision instead of fitting your current routine. Leave this code for non-corner collisions, and add code for corner collisions that will do whatever you want for corners.

Comment: i tried but i am facing a problem in corner

Comment: can you help me in corner colision detection

Comment: It's dangerous to go alone, take this: http://www.box2dflash.org/